# Make a request every one minute with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I began to develop in `Node.js` today and I think an application that performs several requests to know the server uptime. I need **every request completion the function is performed again** as a while loop. 

Is it possible to do this in Node.js?

My basic code

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

request({
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    method: "GET",
    timeout: 10000,
    followRedirect: true,
    maxRedirects: 10
},function(error, response, body){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log('sucess!');
    }else{
        console.log('error' + response.statusCode);
    }
});
```

PS : Sorry if it's a stupid question or duplicate

Comment: look at JS `setTimeout` or `setInterval` functions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

JavaScript has a `setInterval` function, likewise in NodeJS.  You could wrap the function you provided into a `setInterval` loop.

The `setInterval`'s arguments are `(callback, time)`, where `time` is represented through milliseconds...  So lets do a bit of math...

`1s = 1000ms` and `1m = 60s`, so `60 * 1000 = 60000`

```
var requestLoop = setInterval(function(){
  request({
      url: "http://www.google.com",
      method: "GET",
      timeout: 10000,
      followRedirect: true,
      maxRedirects: 10
  },function(error, response, body){
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
          console.log('sucess!');
      }else{
          console.log('error' + response.statusCode);
      }
  });
}, 60000);

// If you ever want to stop it...  clearInterval(requestLoop)
```

Comment: very good article about setTimeout and setInterval here: https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval